# Android - Getting SharedPreferences and putting it in a class

Tags: java, android

I have this class wherein it gets the `sharedPreferences` put it in a variable and use that variable to `$POST` to my PHP file.

```
public class NetworkOperations extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

String awesomeString = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("key", "");

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://usamobileapp.pe.hu/webservice/viewGradesJSON.php");
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "somevalue"));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        Log.d("Http Response:", (response.getEntity()).toString());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

Here's the problem:

[image: this is underlined red]

I'm a beginner so I don't seem to grasp what the problem is.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

"this" must be a context, but your "this" is an AsyncTask.

You might want to get your context in public constructor:

```
public NetworkOperations(Context context){
  this.context = context;
  this.awesomeString = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("key", "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getDaultSharedPreferences` expect a Context object as parameter. `this`, in your case, refers to the `AsyncTask` subclass, which isn't a context. Activity on the other hand inherits from `ContextWrapper`. That's why you don't get a compile time error, if you put that line on an `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

this here is the context of AsyncTask class.

getDefaultSharedPreferences takes context as variable where :

context is The context of the preferences whose values are wanted.

So make sure context is attached to Activity's context